# Display SQLite output in TK python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, sqlite

Im trying to get a row from my db to display on a tk text widget if 1 and remove from display if 0.

The code I have so far shows the row for one card. When I scan a seccond time I get an error of.

```
SQLite objects created in a thread can be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 6740 and this is thread id 6320
<traceback object at 0x02AAC418>
<class 'sqlite3.ProgrammingError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\rfid\main2.py", line 66, in <module>
    cardmonitor.addObserver( cardobserver )
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartcard\CardMonitoring.py", line 105, in addObserver
    observer.update(self, (self.rmthread.cards, []))
  File "C:\rfid\main2.py", line 56, in update
    a(tag)
  File "C:\rfid\main2.py", line 25, in a
    root.mainloop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1017, in mainloop
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Main code below

```
import sqlite3 as db
import os
from prettytable import from_db_cursor
from smartcard.scard import *
from smartcard.util import toHexString
from prettytable import from_db_cursor
from smartcard.CardMonitoring import CardMonitor, CardObserver
import time
from Tkinter import Tk, BOTH, INSERT, Text

def main(tag):

       q = "SELECT * FROM CARDS WHERE TAG=?"
       up = "UPDATE CARDS SET FLAG = (CASE WHEN FLAG=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHERE TAG=?"
       id = "SELECT * FROM CARDS WHERE TAG=?"
       cursor.execute(q, (tag,))
       cursor.execute(up, (tag,))
       conn.commit()
       for row in cursor.execute(id, (tag,)):
        print row [1] + row[2] #debugging to console
        r1 = str(row[1])
        r2 = str(row[2])
        msg = str(r1 + r2)
        text_widget = Text(root, font='times 40 bold', bg='Green')
        text_widget.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=0)
        text_widget.tag_configure('tag-center', wrap='word', justify='center')
        text_widget.insert(INSERT, msg, 'tag-center')
        root.mainloop()
class printobserver( CardObserver ):
    def update( self, observable, (addedcards, removedcards) ):
        previousIdString = ""
        idString = ""
        for card in addedcards:
         if addedcards:
            hresult, hcontext = SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER)
            assert hresult==SCARD_S_SUCCESS
            hresult, readers = SCardListReaders(hcontext, [])
            assert len(readers)>0
            reader = readers[0]
            hresult, hcard, dwActiveProtocol = SCardConnect(
             hcontext,
             reader,
             SCARD_SHARE_SHARED,
             SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 | SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1)
            hresult, response = SCardTransmit(hcard,dwActiveProtocol,[0xFF,0xCA,0x00,0x00,0x04])
            v = toHexString(response, format=0)
            tag = str(v)
            main(tag)
conn = db.connect('cards3.db')
root = Tk()
while True:
 cursor = conn.cursor()
 cardmonitor = CardMonitor()
 cardobserver = printobserver()
 cardmonitor.addObserver( cardobserver )
 cardmonitor.deleteObserver( cardobserver )
 time.sleep( 2 )
```

**update:**
From answers below i have now tired the following.

Moved conn.cursor into class but same. Different error being `Coursor is not defined`

```
import sqlite3 as db
import os
from prettytable import from_db_cursor
from smartcard.scard import *
from smartcard.util import toHexString
from prettytable import from_db_cursor
from smartcard.CardMonitoring import CardMonitor, CardObserver
import time
from Tkinter import Tk, BOTH, INSERT, Text

def main(tag):

       q = "SELECT * FROM CARDS WHERE TAG=?"
       up = "UPDATE CARDS SET FLAG = (CASE WHEN FLAG=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHERE TAG=?"
       id = "SELECT * FROM CARDS WHERE TAG=?"
       cursor.execute(q, (tag,))
       cursor.execute(up, (tag,))
       conn.commit()
       for row in cursor.execute(id, (tag,)):
        print row [1] + " has been checked " + ('in' if row[2] else 'out')
        r1 = str(row[1])
        r2 = str(row[2])
        mseg = str(r1 + r2)
        text_widget = Text(root, font='times 40 bold', bg='Green')
        text_widget.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=0)
        text_widget.tag_configure('tag-center', wrap='word', justify='center')
        text_widget.insert(INSERT, r1 + r2, 'tag-center')
        root.mainloop()

class printobserver( CardObserver ):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    def update( self, observable, (addedcards, removedcards) ):
        previousIdString = ""
        idString = ""
        for card in addedcards:
         if addedcards:
            hresult, hcontext = SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER)
            assert hresult==SCARD_S_SUCCESS
            hresult, readers = SCardListReaders(hcontext, [])
            assert len(readers)>0
            reader = readers[0]
            hresult, hcard, dwActiveProtocol = SCardConnect(
             hcontext,
             reader,
             SCARD_SHARE_SHARED,
             SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 | SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1)
            hresult, response = SCardTransmit(hcard,dwActiveProtocol,[0xFF,0xCA,0x00,0x00,0x04])
            v = toHexString(response, format=0)
            tag = str(v)
            main(tag)

conn = db.connect('cards3.db')
root = Tk()
while True:

 cardmonitor = CardMonitor()
 cardobserver = printobserver()
 cardmonitor.addObserver( cardobserver )
 cardmonitor.deleteObserver( cardobserver )
 time.sleep( 2 )
```

Have also tired putting in main and update but still same error

```
def main(tag):
       cursor = conn.cursor
       q = "SELECT * FROM CARDS WHERE TAG=?"
       up = "UPDATE CARDS SET FLAG = (CASE WHEN FLAG=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHERE TAG=?"
       id = "SELECT * FROM CARDS WHERE TAG=?"
       cursor.execute(q, (tag,))
       cursor.execute(up, (tag,))
       conn.commit()
       for row in cursor.execute(id, (tag,)):
        print row [1] + " has been checked " + ('in' if row[2] else 'out')
        r1 = str(row[1])
        r2 = str(row[2])
        mseg = str(r1 + r2)
        text_widget = Text(root, font='times 40 bold', bg='Green')
        text_widget.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=0)
        text_widget.tag_configure('tag-center', wrap='word', justify='center')
        text_widget.insert(INSERT, r1 + r2, 'tag-center')
        root.mainloop()

def update( self, observable, (addedcards, removedcards) ):
            previousIdString = ""
            idString = ""
            for card in addedcards:
             if addedcards:
                hresult, hcontext = SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER)
                assert hresult==SCARD_S_SUCCESS
                hresult, readers = SCardListReaders(hcontext, [])
                assert len(readers)>0
                reader = readers[0]
                hresult, hcard, dwActiveProtocol = SCardConnect(
                 hcontext,
                 reader,
                 SCARD_SHARE_SHARED,
                 SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 | SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1)
                hresult, response = SCardTransmit(hcard,dwActiveProtocol,[0xFF,0xCA,0x00,0x00,0x04])
                v = toHexString(response, format=0)
                tag = str(v)
                main(tag)
                cursor = conn.cursor
```

If i remove all the TK stuff and put `cursor = conn.cursor` above `while True:` I can keep scanning cards with no issues

```
def main(tag):
           cursor = conn.cursor
           q = "SELECT * FROM CARDS WHERE TAG=?"
           up = "UPDATE CARDS SET FLAG = (CASE WHEN FLAG=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHERE TAG=?"
           id = "SELECT * FROM CARDS WHERE TAG=?"
           cursor.execute(q, (tag,))
           cursor.execute(up, (tag,))
           conn.commit()
           for row in cursor.execute(id, (tag,)):
            print row [1] + " has been checked " + ('in' if row[2] else 'out')
```

Comment: `SQLite objects created in a thread can be used in that same thread.` Grab output not variable !

Comment: As in put it to a txt file then read it in?

Comment: You seem to be calling `mainloop` multiple times. Why are you calling it in every time `main` gets called? It needs to be called exactly once for the life of your program. That may not be the cause of this specific problem, but it's definitely a problem.

Comment: Also, why are you generating a new `sqlite3.conn.cursor()` _inside_ a `while`-loop?

Comment: `Mainloop()` was ment to be called once. i realised i put it in the wrong place so fixed it but forgot to remove old one. As for `conn.cursor` put it there to see if it would work as got error when outside `while loop`

Answer (score 0):

`SQLite objects created in a thread can be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 6740 and this is thread id 6320`

`class printobserver(CardObserver)` has to be creating a new thread, `sqlite3` does not support much concurrency. However, it does across different processes. Notice this snip from your code:

**printobserver**

```
main(tag)
```

**main**

```
q = "SELECT * FROM CARDS WHERE TAG=?"
       up = "UPDATE CARDS SET FLAG = (CASE WHEN FLAG=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHERE TAG=?"
       id = "SELECT * FROM CARDS WHERE TAG=?"
       cursor.execute(q, (tag,))
       cursor.execute(up, (tag,))
       conn.commit()
```

**global namespace `while-loop`**

```
 cardobserver = printobserver()
 cardmonitor.addObserver( cardobserver )
 cardmonitor.deleteObserver( cardobserver )
```

Since you are calling `main()` from your `printobserver` object (clearly this object is creating a new thread each time), you spawned `cursor` in the main thread in the global namespace, and you are calling cursor within `main()` which is now executed from a new thread, you are getting this error.

Since you are not using the `cursor` externally from `main()`, I recommend connecting to the database at the top of `main()`, initializing the `cursor`, then doing whatever you need to do, and disconnecting from the database at the bottom of main. Alternatively, you can do this within the `printobserver` object, as the cursor initialization will still be within the same thread as `main()`.